# Playing files audio .aac with jQuery

Tags: jquery, audio, aac

Any hints? I'm trying this: http://www.jplayer.org/ with bad results.

Bad results means, it does not work and not errors at all.

So, I'm looking for an alternative that support .aac files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="" type="audio/aac">    
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```